# Can I earn gold tokens in Hasbro's Risk on Android?

Tags: risk

Hasbro's Risk for Android only seems to have 2 ways to gain gold coins (which are required to play any games): Log in once a day, to earn 1 coin, or buy paid version ($6) with no coin limit.

Is there any other way to earn more coins in the free version of the game or is that version truly limited to 1 game a day against PC or 1 game every 2 days against other players?

Answer (score -1):

It's a single token every 6 hours.